# Запись данных в память приложения

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences, хранение-данных

Несколько запутался как прописать сохранение данных в приложении.
Необходимо сохранять id случайного изображения (randomImageId) до конца суток (это как-то можно прописать без дополнительного метода по очистке данных?)

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";

public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_INDEX = "index";
SharedPreferences mSettings;


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final TextView infotext = findViewById(R.id.infotext);
    ImageButton resetbutton = findViewById(R.id.resetbutton);
    infotext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    resetbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
    editor //some code
    editor.apply();






    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    final Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    final ImageButton resetbutton = findViewById(R.id.resetbutton);


    final ImageButton cardbutton = findViewById(R.id.cardbutton);
    cardbutton.setTag(1);
    final TextView infotext = findViewById(R.id.infotext);


    final int[] imageIds = {
            R.drawable.n00,
            R.drawable.n01,
            R.drawable.n02,
            R.drawable.n03,
            R.drawable.n04,
            R.drawable.n05,
            R.drawable.n06,
            R.drawable.n07,
            R.drawable.n08,
            R.drawable.n09,
            R.drawable.n10,
            R.drawable.n11,
            R.drawable.n12,
            R.drawable.n13,
            R.drawable.n14,
            R.drawable.n15,
            R.drawable.n16,
            R.drawable.n17,
            R.drawable.n18,
            R.drawable.n19,
            R.drawable.n20,
            R.drawable.n21,
            R.drawable.n22,
    };
    final String[] texts = {
            getString(R.string.s00),
            "Mage",
            "Pristess",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7",
            "8",
            "9",
            "10",
            "11",
            "12",
            "13",
            "14",
            "15",
            "16",
            "17",
            "18",
            "19",
            "20",
            "21",
            "22"
    };
    cardbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            infotext.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            int status = (Integer) v.getTag();
            if (status == 1) {

                Random generator = new Random();
                int index = generator.nextInt(imageIds.length);
                int randomImageId = imageIds [index];
                String text = texts[index];
                cardbutton.setImageResource(randomImageId);
                infotext.setText(text);
                infotext.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff5013"));
                infotext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                resetbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                v.setTag(0);
                vibrator.vibrate(50);

            } else {
                infotext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                resetbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                v.setTag(0);
            }
        }

    });
    resetbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем чистить? Сохраняй вместе с датой, а когда считываешь смотри прошедшее время.

Comment: Спасибо, отличная мысль. Так еще статистику вести можно. 
Ну а записать то данные как?)

Comment: @Guahoo любым удобным для вас способом, хоть DB, хоть Preferences

Comment: В теории я знаю как это сделать. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это выразить с помощью синтаксиса